# How to hide keyboard in iOS mobile automation using Appium

Tags: ios, appium

I am using iOS version of 10.2 and xcode version is 8.3.

Can anyone let me know how to hide the keyboard in iOS mobile automation using Appium?

programming language used: Java.

Answer (score 2):

I tried `driver.hideKeyboard()`, but it doesn't work for me.

So, I tried with way:

1. by pressing the button specified key name and way
2. inspect key coordinate with appium and perform action. Both ways are work for me.

```
// way 1
driver.findElementByXPath(String.format("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name='%s']", "Done")).click();

// way 2
TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
touchAction.tap(new PointOption().withCoordinates(345, 343)).perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [java_client library](https://github.com/appium/java-client) methods:

```
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Hide keyboard").click();

driver.hideKeyboard(HideKeyboardStrategy.TAP_OUTSIDE);

driver.hideKeyboard(HideKeyboardStrategy.PRESS_KEY, "Done");
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that "Done" is not part of the keyboard group. So I tried to use the name "Done" as my reference to get the element. I tried this on my end and it works.

```
driver.findElementByName("Done").click();
```

The "driver" set declared as IOSDriver.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code snippet to hide keyboard:

```
driver.getKeyboard().pressKey(Keys.RETURN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Python - 2020:

```
    @staticmethod
    def hide_keyboard(platform):
        """
        Hides the software keyboard on the device.
        """
        if platform == "Android":
            driver.hide_keyboard()
        elif platform == "iOS":
            driver.find_element_by_name("Done").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

i prefer to tap last key on keyboard for iOS instead of hide:

```
    @HowToUseLocators(iOSXCUITAutomation = LocatorGroupStrategy.CHAIN)
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(className = "XCUIElementTypeKeyboard")
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(className = "XCUIElementTypeButton")
    private List<IOSElement> last_iOSKeyboardKey;

    @HowToUseLocators(iOSXCUITAutomation = LocatorGroupStrategy.CHAIN)
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(className = "XCUIElementTypeKeyboard")
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(iOSNsPredicate = "type == 'XCUIElementTypeButton' AND " +
            "(name CONTAINS[cd] 'Done' OR name CONTAINS[cd] 'return' " +
            "OR name CONTAINS[cd] 'Next' OR name CONTAINS[cd] 'Go')")
    private IOSElement last_iOSKeyboardKey_real;

    public boolean tapLastKeyboardKey_iOS() {
        System.out.println("   tapLastKeyboardKey_iOS()");
        boolean bool = false;
        setLookTiming(3);
        try {
// one way            
//bool =  tapElement_XCTest(last_iOSKeyboardKey.get(last_iOSKeyboardKey.size()-1));
// slightly faster way
            bool =  tapElement_XCTest(last_iOSKeyboardKey_real);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("   tapLastKeyboardKey_iOS(): looks like keyboard closed!");
            System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
        }
        setDefaultTiming();
        return bool;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using all of above method. In some case, it doesn't work perfectly. In my way, it will tap on top left of keyboard.

> ```
> public void hideKeyboard() {
>     if (isAndroid()) {
>         driver.hideKeyboard();
>     } else {
>         IOSDriver iosDriver = (IOSDriver) driver;
>         // TODO: Just work for Text Field
>         // iosDriver.hideKeyboard();
>         // TODO: Tap outside of Keyboard
>         IOSElement element = (IOSElement) iosDriver.findElementByClassName("XCUIElementTypeKeyboard");
>         Point keyboardPoint = element.getLocation();
>         TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
>         touchAction.tap(keyboardPoint.getX() + 2, keyboardPoint.getY() - 2).perform();
>         try {
>             Thread.sleep(500);
>         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Since the IOS device keyboard doesn't have any "Done" or "Enter" buttons anymore so we can't use any of the Appium server utility interface like HideKeyboardStrategy.

I basically used the TouchAction class tap method to tap at top of the screen and dismiss the keyboard.

```
        TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
        int topY = driver.manage().window().getSize().height / 8;
        int pressX = driver.manage().window().getSize().width / 2;
        touchAction.tap(new PointOption().withCoordinates(pressX, topY)).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick & simple solution :

I always try to **tap anywhere on screen**, may be on

- Static text
- Image

after entering to hide keyboard unless I explicitly has requirement of interacting with keyboard. This works pretty well for me. Try it :)